# Hardness of a problem which is the sum of two NP-Hard problems

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, np-complete, np-hard

Consider the problem of computing an exponential sum over a certain function $g(x)=f(x)+h(x)$, that is computing

$$\sum_{x}g(x)=\sum_{x}f(x)+\sum_{x}h(x)$$

now if we know that $\sum_{x}f(x)$ and $\sum_{x}h(x)$ are two NP-Hard problems, what can we say about the hardness of $\sum_{x}g(x)$?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Nothing.

**Lower bound:** Suppose $h(x) = -f(x)$. Then $\sum_x g(x) = 0$, which is trivial to compute. If $\sum_x f(x)$ is NP-hard to compute, then $\sum_x h(x)$ will be too, but $\sum_x g(x)$ will be easy to compute.

**Upper bound:** Suppose $h(x) = f(x)$. Then $\sum_x g(x) = 2 \sum_x f(x)$, which is as hard as computing $\sum_x f(x)$, which is assumed to be NP-hard. Since NP-hard means (roughly speaking) NP-complete *or harder*, there is no upper bound on the complexity; it could be arbitrarily hard to compute $\sum_x g(x)$.

Comment: It might also be that the sum is not NP-hard.

Comment: @kutschkem: If you can make a nontrivial example I'd like to see it.

Comment: @Joshua Graph theory is likely full of them - computing the number of graphs with n vertices and a certain property, then computing the number of graphs with n vertices without a certain property.  Computing the number of graphs with n vertices is comparatively easy.  If that's not non-trivial enough for you, I'm pretty sure computing which graphs have which chromatic number is NP-hard when the chromatic number is >3, but not for <3.  So you could do f=>3, h=>4+, and g=>3+.

Comment: @Spitemaster Thanks, yes that's the kind of problems I had in mind.